# Reuse function across multiple acitivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a doubt related to Android. My app main feature is taking photos of different objects don't matter what objects. I have a main menu where I can do that and have another view where I have a button to capture photo too, so basically I can do it in 2 different views the code should be the same.

I want to place the code inside a empty capture activity and reuse it in different views, how can I do that?

**My code to capture:**

```
private void sendImage(String encodedImage){
    //inicialize a map with pair key value
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


    // Add form fields to the map
    params.put("base64", encodedImage);
    URL = URL + "\\" + "Tulipa";
    Log.d("url",URL);



    /**
     * Efetua um pedido ao servidor
     *
     * @param URl    url do servidor a aceder
     * @param JSONObject objeto json a ser retornado através do access point
     *
     */
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //TODO verificar o status code da resposta apenas deverá fazer login caso seja 200
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this,MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            String body;

            if(error.networkResponse.data!=null) {
                String statusCode = String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                try {
                    body = new String(error.networkResponse.data,"UTF-8");
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(body);
                    Log.d("body",String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("message")));
                    showToast(String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("message")));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    showToast("You need to connect to the internet!");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("json:","problems decoding jsonObj");
                }
            }

            //do stuff with the body...
        }
    });

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.add(request); // adiciona a request à queue pronta a ser executada
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ImageHandler{
     public static void sendImage(String encodedImage){
         ....
     }
}
```

in MainActivity : `ImageHandler.sendImage("myString");`

Jonathan Aste's answer is good too if you need to send that image from activites, if you need to send them from activities/other classes you can use mine answer

Answer (score 1):

First create a base activity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
     protected void sendImage(String encodedImage){
        //inicialize a map with pair key value
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


        // Add form fields to the map
        params.put("base64", encodedImage);
        URL = URL + "\\" + "Tulipa";
        Log.d("url",URL);



        /**
         * Efetua um pedido ao servidor
         *
         * @param URl    url do servidor a aceder
         * @param JSONObject objeto json a ser retornado através do access point
         *
         */
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        //TODO verificar o status code da resposta apenas deverá fazer login caso seja 200
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this,MainMenu.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                String body;

                if(error.networkResponse.data!=null) {
                    String statusCode = String.valueOf(error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                    try {
                        body = new String(error.networkResponse.data,"UTF-8");
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(body);
                        Log.d("body",String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("message")));
                        showToast(String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("message")));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        showToast("You need to connect to the internet!");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("json:","problems decoding jsonObj");
                    }
                }

                //do stuff with the body...
            }
        });

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(request); // adiciona a request à queue pronta a ser executada
    }`

}
```

then make the activities you need to have this behaviour extend your class

```
public class MyActivity1 extends BaseActivity{

    public void yourMethod(){
        sendImage("your string");
    }
}
```

other activity

```
public class MyActivity2 extends BaseActivity{

    public void yourMethod(){
        sendImage("your string");
    }
}
```